# what's SparkSQL SQL query to write into JDBC table?

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

For SQL query in Spark.

For read, we can read jdbc by

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE jdbcTable
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS dbtable ...;
```

For write, what is the query to write the data to the remote JDBC table using SQL?

**NOTE: I want it to be SQL query.**
plz provide the pure "SQL query" that can write to jdbc when using HiveContext.sql(...) of SparkSQL.

Answer (score 2):

An `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE` will write to your database using the JDBC connection:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jdbcTemp;
CREATE TABLE jdbcTemp
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (...);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE jdbcTemp
SELECT * FROM my_spark_data;
DROP TABLE jdbcTemp;
```

Comment: This worked for me. Other answers don't use Spark SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the dataframe with jdbc similar to follows.

```
df.write.jdbc(url, "TEST.BASICCREATETEST", new Properties)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. If you want to save a dataframe into an existing table you can use

```
df.insertIntoJDBC(url, table, overwrite)
```

and if you want to create new table to save this dataframe, the you can use

```
df.createJDBCTable(url, table, allowExisting)
```