# how to load data from csv to mysql database in Spark?

Tags: mysql, scala, csv, apache-spark, jdbc

I would like to load data from csv to mySql as a batch. But I could see the tutorials/logic to insert the data from csv to hive database. Could anyone kindly help me to achieve the above integration in spark using scala?

Comment: What problems have you had doing this? Are you able to make a JDBC connection to mysql? Then you can `write("jdbc")` on a dataset...

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169319/whats-sparksql-sql-query-to-write-into-jdbc-table

Comment: And you can find much documentation... https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#writing-data-to-jdbc

Comment: @cricket_007 Now I am able to have entire data from csv as dataFrame. But I am bit confused to load the same dataFrame to insert it into a mysql database.

Comment: As shown twice. You `df.write` into a new source. `jdbc` is the format method. Give it your database options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a reason why those tutorials don't exist. This task is very straightforward. Here is minimal working example:

```
val dbStr = "jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]]"

spark
  .read
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("some/path/to/file.csv")
  .write
    .mode("overwrite")
    .jdbc(dbStr, tablename, props)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the `dataframe` reading `CSV` using spark session and write using the method `jdbc` with `mysql` Connection properties

```
val url = "jdbc:mysql://[host][:port][/[database]]"
val table = "mytable"
val property = new Properties()

spark
  .read
    .csv("some/path/to/file.csv")
  .write
    .jdbc(url, table, property)
```