# Spark JDBC direct path inserts

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

When writing data from Hive to Oracle using (Py)Spark JDBC connector, I run into problems with the buffer cache on Oracle.
So my question is if there is a way to bypass oracle buffer cache by using direct path inserts (as suggested here https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/architecture/instance/SGA/database-buffer-cache/index).
I was wondering if I can just use the `initSessionStatement` as described in the docs. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html
Something along the lines of `option("sessionInitStatement", """BEGIN execute immediate 'alter session set "<DIRECT PATH INSERT PARAMETER?>"=true'; END;""")`.
Another approach I'm wondering if it could work is using spark sql to insert into oracle as described in this answer [what's SparkSQL SQL query to write into JDBC table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169319/whats-sparksql-sql-query-to-write-into-jdbc-table) and then specifiying the `/+ append +/` for direct path insert.
Does anyone have experience with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you need that? Direct path insert might have various limitations(like can not be parallelized easily), and there are cases where Oracle will ignore your hint(due to triggers, FK, ...) PS: Since 19c Oracle JDBC drivers have support for direct path ETL API.

Comment: I'd also be fine avoiding it. The problem is that my DBA complained about my spark jdbc job since it was slowing down the whole database by filling too much buffer cache.  
I'm mainly using spark instead of sqoop or other tools since it proved faster and parallelizes well for writing to partitioned tables

Comment: sessionInitStatement may work though the documentation says it is used for reading.

Comment: @salim do you know what the option would be? I only found the one for reading, couldn't find a parameter for writing

Comment: for writing you need to create new dataframewriter inherit from jdbcwriter. There you can create a new option for hint, use that to append the hint to the SQL fired by jdbcwriter. I don't see any explicit option.